# PgfPlots - Plot semilogx of a matched filter

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

I tried to plot a frequency response of a matched filter, which its response defined by:

H(f) = [image]

Since x (=f) runs from *very big negative value* to *very big positive value*, and y  (=H(f)) runs only between 0 to 1, I used Pgfplots Semilogxaxis. My code look like this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{semilogxaxis}[xlabel=Frequency, ylabel=Gain, xmin=1, xmax=20000, ymin=0, ymax=2]
      \addplot[domain=1:1e4,color=red] {((2*pi*x)^2 + 10^6)/(11(2*pi*x)^2 + 10^6 + 10^4)};
    \end{semilogxaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I got the next error message:

`! Package PGF Math Error: You've asked me to divide '195.000000000' by '0.0', but I cannot divide any number by '0.0'.`

I'm breaking my head over here, but can't figure out where exactly there's a division by 0.

Nevertheless, if anyone have a better idea how should I plot this function in Latex, I'd **love** to hear it, 'cause I've been sitting on this way-too-much-time...

Thanks.

Comment: I think there is just a typo in your equation, you're missing the `*` in `(11*(2*pi*x)...`. Could you try if that fixes the problem? If it doesn't, could you complete your code snippet to make a minimal compilable example document (starting from `\documentclass`)?

Comment: Also, you say "x (=f) runs from very big negative value". I guess that's a typo, since that wouldn't work with a logarithmic domain, and you're correctly using a strictly positive domain in your code.

Comment: @Jake, actually - that wasn't a typo, more like heart-wish :) On one hand - x (=f) can be negative (by theorem, of course), and on the other hand - I want the scale of x to be logarithmic, since the change in x is way faster than the change in y. I know there's no negative values for log-based numbers, I just can't find the right option to plot x in logarithmic manner, and still have the negative values. Help will appreciate on this as well :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is just as Jake commented.  The `*` for multiplication was missing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{semilogxaxis}[xlabel=Frequency, ylabel=Gain, xmin=1, xmax=20000, ymin=0, ymax=2]
      \addplot[domain=1:1e4,color=red]
        {((2*pi*x)^2 + 10^6)/(11*(2*pi*x)^2 + 10^6 + 10^4)};
        %                       ^
        %  This `*' was missing |
    \end{semilogxaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I'd also use autosizing with turned off `enlarge x limits` and also `smooth` the curve.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{semilogxaxis}[
      enlarge x limits=false,
      xlabel=Frequency,
      ylabel=Gain]
      \addplot[domain=1:1e4,red,smooth]
        {((2*pi*x)^2 + 10^6)/(11*(2*pi*x)^2 + 10^6 + 10^4)};
    \end{semilogxaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]